# Inverse functions a proof - Spivak

Tags: calculus

I have the second edition of Spivak. In the chapter "Inverse Functions" Lemma 2 states

> Let f be a continuous one to one function defined on an ivneral, let $a$ and $b$ be two points of the inveral, and suppose that $f(a) < f(b)$. If $c$ is a point of the interval with $c < a$, then $f(c) < f(a)$; and similarly, if $b < c$, then $f(b) < f(c)$.
>
> Proof: Consider the case $c < a$. Suppose first that $f(c) > f(b)$. Then Lemma 1 applied $c < a <b$ would imply that $f(a) > f(b)$, which is false. Hence $f(c) < f(b)$. But now Lemma 1 may be applied to $c < a <b$ to conclude that $f(c) < f(a) < f(b)$. The case $b < c$ is handled similarly.

Why does he assume $a <b$ in $c < a < b$ in the proof? How does know that? Is it because if $b < c < a$, then he can't assume $f(c) > f(b)$? If so, isn't he using the lemma and proving it? Some circular logic going on??

Comment: I'm not sure you're quoting it correctly. For example, consider $f(x) = - x$ in the interval $[0,1]$, and take $ a= 0.9, b = 0.1$, we have $f(0.9) < f(0.1)$. But with $ c = 0.5$, we do not have $f(c) < f(a)$.

Comment: Spivak has written many books. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: His 'Calculus' for first years

Comment: You should get a more recent edition. I just checked out Chap. 12 and it doesn't have a single lemma..

Comment: I have an online pdf of the 3rd edition, but the page got deleted in my book. So I have to reference an old edition

Comment: What page are you missing? I can post the missing page or even send you the pdf for the 3rd edition - at least in Chap. 12 it isn't missing any pages.

Comment: Page 231; when he talks about Theorem 2

Comment: There is some confusion here. The discussion seems to be about a continuous one-one function on an open interval $I$ and $a, b$ are two of its interior points. It is assumed that $a < b$ and $f(a) < f(b)$. This assumption is nothing serious and one can continue the argument by assuming reverse case $b < a$. Another point $c$ of the open interval $I$ but outside $[a, b]$ is chosen and then two cases $c < a$ and $ b < c$ are considered. And in both cases I think the author is trying to show that $f$ is strictly increasing. One more case of $c \in (a, b)$ is also needed.